# rsyslog include a date substring in a string value

Tags: elasticsearch, rsyslog, rainerscript

I feel like there's something simple staring at me that I'm missing on this but have been through the docs several times and haven't found a way to include the date in a string.

Here is my working custom rsyslog config shipping logs into elastic:

```
module(load="imfile" PollingInterval="10")
module(load="omelasticsearch")

input(type="imfile"
      persistStateInterval="10"
      file="/var/log/myapp/myapp.log"
      tag="my_app_log")

if ($syslogtag == "my_app_log") then {

      action(type="omelasticsearch"
          server=["172.x.x.x", "172.x.x.x", "172.x.x.x"]
          serverport="9200"
          searchIndex="app-logs"
          )
      stop
  }
```

I'd like to append a date string to the name of the searchIndex and tried using a template:

```
module(load="imfile" PollingInterval="10")
module(load="omelasticsearch")

template(name="string_template" type="string" string="app-logs-$now")

input(type="imfile"
      persistStateInterval="10"
      file="/var/log/myapp/myapp.log"
      tag="my_app_log")

if ($syslogtag == "my_app_log") then {

      action(type="omelasticsearch"
          server=["172.x.x.x", "172.x.x.x", "172.x.x.x"]
          serverport="9200"
          searchIndex="string_template" <-- (results in an index in elasticsearch called string_template) 
          )
      stop
  }
```

Then the same as above but without the quotes like I would have expected when specifying a variable rather than a string:

```
module(load="imfile" PollingInterval="10")
module(load="omelasticsearch")

template(name="string_template" type="string" string="app-logs-$now")

input(type="imfile"
      persistStateInterval="10"
      file="/var/log/myapp/myapp.log"
      tag="my_app_log")

if ($syslogtag == "my_app_log") then {

      action(type="omelasticsearch"
          server=["172.x.x.x", "172.x.x.x", "172.x.x.x"]
          serverport="9200"
          searchIndex=string_template <-- (does nothing, no index created and no errors in syslog) 
          )
      stop
  }
```

To troubleshoot, removing the replacement variable from the template doesn't work to pass a simple string:

```
template(name="string_template" type="string" string="app-logs")
```

Some of the values tried for "searchIndex=":

- app_logs-$now (no template)
- "app_logs-$now" (no template)
- "app_logs-%$now%" (no template)
- string_template
- "string_template"
- $string_template
- "$string_template"
- %$string_template%
- "%$string_template%"

Comment: [there is/was a way to do it](https://sematext.com/blog/recipe-rsyslog-elasticsearch-kibana/), perhaps it's an issue with my version of rsyslog which is the latest on the ubuntu 20.04 official repo (rsyslogd 8.2001.0).

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? Is the date representing the log creation date, the current date or a *random* date? and what format are your logs in?

Comment: searchIndex is the name of the index created in Elasticsearch if it doesn't already exist that the logs are indexed under. I wanted an index name created with the today's date like index_name-2022-12-15 to stick to the current convention we use but I've pretty much given up on this and have gone the route of living with everything going in under the same index and using an index lifecycle policy to manage the size of the index.

Comment: I'm not really familiar with elasticsearch, so I don't know how it's handled there. But rsyslog can handle any log format, as long as you define it. Also, have you thought about generating a file per day and label that? Or what exactly is the purpose of the index? Why not just use the log generation date?

Comment: all I'm trying to do is use the current date to form a string to use as the value for "searchIndex=" no elastic knowledge required, it's just the name of the index the logs are indexed under but as far as the rsyslog config is concerned, it's just passing a string value to searchIndex=

Comment: I'm not following. So you want to use the **name** of the logfile as value of the `searchIndex` param?

Comment: the question is in the title "include a date substring in a string value", that's actually all the information that's required to fully understand the question. the rest is for context and is confusing matters apparently. I wanted a string "mystring-2022-12-23" that I could then use to pass as a value to a field that takes a string value, in this case "searchIndex=" You don't need to understand anything about how that string value is subsequently used, I'm just trying to build a string.

Comment: I'd say it does matter. Rsyslog isn't a programming language, it's a simple utility for log processing. Therefore it may be solved differently than what you have in mind. It's about explaining the problem and the goal, to maybe find a different way to solve the problem. But if that's the only way you want to solve it **no**, it's not possible; but you could use **backticks** to specify **environment variables** as action parameters.

Comment: thanks @eDonkey I've come to the same conclusion and managed the index lifecycle in elastic without an index per day, it doesn't really matter technically, I was just trying to adhere to the current standard way we do things.